# Can't find the element?

Tags: python, selenium

I run a webdriver with an extension, and im trying to do automation with it. I need to click on the Get Started button, but it says Unable to locate element
[image]

Also, here is the XPATH for the button:

```
//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/a
```

Comment: Post the URL and the minimal code

Comment: We can't help here without seeing your code and a link to that page. Not a picture of some it XML block

Comment: It's an extension of Chrome namely Sui Wallet

Answer (score 0):

As @AbiSaran comment.
You should be the minimal code...

anw, if you using selenium version > 4.3 then try this:

```
driver.find_element('xpaht','//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/a')
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work